# want to return the user roleid after successful login

Tags: php, mysql, json

below is my MySQLDao.php

```
<?php
class MySQLDao {
var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;

function __construct() {
$this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
$this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
$this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
$this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
}


// function to open connection

public function openConnection() {
$this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
}

// function to return the connection

public function getConnection() {
return $this->conn;
}

// function to close the connection

public function closeConnection() {
if ($this->conn != null)
$this->conn->close();
}

// function to get user email

public function getUserDetails($email)
{
$returnValue = array();
$sql = "select * from ap_users where user_email='" . $email . "'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row)) {
$returnValue = $row;
}
}
return $returnValue;
}

// get user details using email and password

public function getUserDetailsWithPassword($email, $userPassword, $roleid)
{
$returnValue = array();
$sql = "select id,user_email from ap_users where user_email='" . $email . "' and user_password='" .$userPassword . "' and user_roleid='" . $roleid . "'";
$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
if ($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)) {
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row)) {
$returnValue = $row;
}
}
return $returnValue;
}

// register user with all fields

public function registerUser($email, $password, $username, $fname, $lname,     $mobile, $roleid)
{
$sql = "insert into ap_users set user_email=?, user_password=?, user_username=?, user_fname=?, user_lname=?, user_mobile=?, user_roleid=?";
$statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

if (!$statement)
throw new Exception($statement->error);

$statement->bind_param("sssssss", $email, $password, $username, $fname, $lname, $mobile, $roleid);
$returnValue = $statement->execute();

return $returnValue;
}

}
?>
```

and my UserLogin.php is as under:

```
<?php

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");
$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required field";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password);

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetailsWithPassword($email,$secure_password);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is logged in";
$returnValue["role"] = "'" .$roleid. "'";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {

$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is not found";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

problem here is when i push the $roleid value always it shows null.
result is like this: {"status":"Success","message":"User is logged in","role:"""}

Comment: Are you requesting with ajax ?

Comment: You're not actually setting `$roleid` anywhere? You also don't pass it into your `getUserDetailsWithPassword()` method. That has 3 parameters but you pass two.

Comment: What are the calls to `htmlentities()` doing there? That is _not_ what that function is for! And... using `md5()` to create a `$secure_password` will certainly _not_ create a secure password.

Comment: i am thinking if that will affect on login and it would be then unsuccessful login(because it will compare roleid also) please suggest me the better way.

Comment: What will affect the login procedure? The calls to `htmlentities()`? Certainly they will, they will break it in many cases. Just remove them!

Comment: And note that your current code is open to sql injection attacks. You want to read about the benefits of using "prepared statements" combined with `parameter binding`...

Comment: is your `roleid` same table as your `username` and `password`?

Comment: roleid,username,password are into same table.

Comment: How to push roleid (json) value of user while login in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added MySqlDao getUserDetailsWithPassword() method

$sql = "select id,user_email,**user_roleid** from ap_users where user_email='" . $email . "' and user_password='" .$userPassword . "' and user_roleid='" . $roleid . "'";

and in user login changed

$returnValue["role"] = "'" .$roleid. "'"; line to **$returnValue['user_roleid'] = $userDetails['user_roleid'];**

this accomplish my desired result!